# Enable spelling check by default

Tags: feature-request, editor

I know it is a small thing, but I rely on the spell check more than anyone really should and it is a little irritating to have to right click and do it manually.

Can it be enabled by default for edit summaries and titles?

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_formsControlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms) it looks like it's as easy as:

```
<input type="text" spellcheck="true">
```

Comment: Stack Exchange does not have a spell checking feature.

Comment: @animuson I would guess that it is the browser's spell checking feature that is enabled or not enabled for the particular input or text area

Comment: There is a spellcheck attribute, but Stack Exchange does not use it anywhere. Your browser probably just only enables it on textareas by default. That is a user setting, and a website should not have any say in whether it's enabled or disabled for a user unless they implement their own.

Comment: @animuson looking through the settings on Firefox the only one relating to spell check is under "Browsing", "Check spelling as I type", but it looks like it is enabled by default.

Comment: Looks like Chrome has this covered though...

Comment: If this is controlled by the browser, can you make so that those of us who do not tweak browsers for a living (but simply use them all the time) know how to get browsers in general (or, at least, Firefox in particular) to spell-check the title lines of questions in particular?  Either by making it the same type of entry box as the main question — a text area (but what is it at the moment?) — or telling us how to tweak the Firefox settings to alter this behaviour?

Comment: It would be useful if the `spellcheck="true"` attribute was added to the title bar of SO when going to a Firefox browser — as suggested in the question.  All else apart, I sometimes spot one error in a title and miss other errors in the same title, whereas I don't miss them in the body of the text.  And I do a lot of editing (not the most of anybody, but a lot of it).