# Who is doing the spellcheck when I write a question or an answer on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, editor

I noticed some problems with spellcheck while editing some posts. Apparently the plural of the word 'octant' isn't supposed to be 'octants'. And although both 'color' and 'colour' are acceptable, only the plural 'colors' is fine. 'colours' gets rejected.
I'm not one for pointing fingers, but I would like to know if I can do something about this. So, is the spellcheck feature under the control of Stack Overflow or is it controlled by my browser which is Google Chrome?

The only info I could find on Meta is a very old (2014) question that received this [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262914/enable-spelling-check-by-default#comment54931_262914) about the Stack Overflow editor *not* having a spellcheck.

Comment: Normally, this is a feature of your web browser.

Comment: According to Webster dictionary the plural of octant is [octans](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Octans) not octants.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octant) should probably fix their incorrect article.

Comment: [Octants](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/octants) redirects to [octant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/octant) on that site though, @SecurityHound , so Octants seems to be correct. And the page, for octant, uses *Octants* as an example.

Comment: @SecurityHound Your link isn't for the plural of octant & it isn't even a plural.

Comment: Look at me. I am the spellchecker now.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk [Are you a wizard?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428147/who-is-doing-the-spellcheck-when-i-write-a-question-or-an-answer-on-stack-overfl/428148#comment987097_428148)

Comment: Re *"Apparently the plural of the word 'octant' isn't supposed to be 'octants'."*: That is an example of [a false positive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octant#Noun)—due to the word not being included in that particular spell checker's dictionary (presumably). They probably don't want to include too many words as that would increase the number of false negatives (by including words that are listed as [obsolete or achaic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Obsolete_and_archaic_terms)).

Comment: cont' - Or in other words, you should trust a dictionary and your own judgement much more than a spell checker. It is a really great tool, but still only a tool.

Comment: @SepRoland yes, you are right [we hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/). It must have been awful to be exposed to attempts of jokes. You will receive a refund for your troubles.

Answer (score 11):

Spellchecks are handled by your browser, not by the Stack Overflow editor.

Comment: Spellchecks are handled by you. If you do that with your browser or a dictionary printed on dead trees is an individual choice.